# Adding custom media queries to Bootstrap 3 responsive utility classes

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, media-queries

Is there a way to add a custom media query (i.e. iPad Mini ver. 1-3) to Bootstrap 3 responsive utility classes?

For example, I want the `.hidden-lg` class to exclude iPads, 1-3/minis, and other 768x1024 devices.

Comment: You can add a custom media query to widths, is that what you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In theory it's easy enough, you use a media query to target specific devices, then write your CSS to override the built-in Bootstrap behaviour.

You'll find sources online to help you with the media queries, to get you started you could try http://cssmediaqueries.com/target/

So for example, using the media query from the source above to target the .hidden-lg class on an iPad mini you would start with:

```
@media screen and (device-width: 768px) and (device-height: 1024px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 1) {

.hidden-lg {
        display: initial !important
    }
}
```

In overriding the Bootstrap styling, the standard rules of [CSS specificity](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/) are going to apply. It's possible you may need to add extra attributes to your selector so that your new rule takes priority, e.g.

```
#custom-content .hidden-lg {
...
}
```

Good luck!